# Ubuntu won't boot up, keeps on re starting

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel-atom

I have just installed Ubuntu on my Acer Aspire Revo with an Intel Atom processor and a Nvidia graphics chipset.

initially I had trouble installing, someone on here instructed me to use a nomodset kernel. This was successful and it did install but the graphics were poor. I ran a pre-installed program that scanned for missing drivers. It seems that i wasn't using the Nvidia driver, so I selected this and rebooted.

Once it re-booted, the graphics look better, but after entering my password, the computer just restarts.

I have tried restarting with the left shift down to enter safe mode to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which Nvidia card and which driver?

Comment: Nvidia graphics driver is 195.36.24

Comment: Nvidia Ion graphics - integrated

Comment: Follow the steps listed in my answer and you should be good to go.

Comment: Wrong version. The old ION chipsets should use 340.xx only!

Comment: Can you log into the guest session successfully?  If so the problem is a hidden "config" file in your home directory, probably .Xauthority .

Comment: hi, no can't get on to a guest session either

Answer (score 0):

Open up a terminal before login with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

The first step is uninstalling the nvidia driver:

`sudo apt purge nvidia-*`

Then, upon reboot, What I would recommend is looking up `nvidia` in your Synaptic package manager. `nvidia-340` Should do the trick. Mark `nvidia-340` for installation, apply, and after that you'll have to reboot again. If you get the same rebooting problem after this let me know.

Comment: Thanks, it's not a card as such, it's integrated into the board. I'm not completely familiar with Synaptic package manager, I'm a newbie.

Comment: Synaptic should already be preinstalled, but if it isn't go ahead and install it after following the steps listed in the first half of my answer. It's on the Ubuntu software center or you can type `sudo apt install synaptic` in a terminal. Then after that you can go ahead and follow the second half of the steps (after the "Then, upon reboot" part of my post)

Comment: After removing the installed Nvuidia drivers there's no need to go to Synaptic (and it's *not* installed by default since many years ago). Use `nomodeset` again to boot with generic graphics support, then search for Additional Drivers, select & apply the recommended version (only 340 is recommended for Nvidia ION). Reboot.

Comment: Or you could simply mark `nvidia-340` for installation in Synaptic, apply and reboot. It's unfortunate Synaptic isn't included by default because it is much easier for certain things than the software center (good luck finding any -dev libraries on Muon or Gnome Software). As a side note (off topic) I also use Antix 16.2 32bit and Synaptic is the default package manager for that.

Comment: The problem with doing it your way @CelticWarrior is that it isn't foolproof. Sometimes Ubuntu/Kubuntu/Xubuntu will incorrectly detect which graphics driver is needed, hence why I recommend the foolproof Synaptic method.

Comment: @EliasTurner A given Ubuntu release may not have a certain driver version in its repositories, hence the need to add a PPA sometimes. Other than that it's foolproof (and Synaptic won't give the require version if it isn't in the repos already). And if you want to use command line all the way you can. **What's the point in installing Synaptic for the sole purpose of installing `nvidia-current`?** BTW, `nvidia-current` will install a **wrong** driver.

Comment: I amended my original post to include the `nvidia-340` driver part. Our `nvidia-current` issue should be a thing of the past now. And like I said I just so happen to prefer using Synaptic on all my Unix-alike systems. In my experience Ubuntu software center, then later Gnome Software, is a lot slower for me than plain old synaptic, especially if I had to fallback to my noveau drivers in a case like the OPs, or am troubleshooting some other problems.

Comment: Also, `ubuntu-desktop` is already installed (and it's just a meta-package anyway); no need to remove `xorg.conf` (it's no longer used) and once you remove the proprietary Nvidia drivers it automatically defaults to `nouveau`.  So, please, edit and correct your answer and give a nudge so I can upvote.

Comment: You cannot search driver versions in the Software Center or Muon @CelticWarrior. If you just purge nvidia and then reboot and select the pre-configured Nvidia driver again it is very likely to give the same issues again (happened to me before personally). Synaptic allows you to look up the exact version necessary, such as nvidia-340 in OP's case, and has also solved my problems in cases such as the OP's.

Comment: If you know the version to install you can simply do `apt-get install nvidia-xxx`. Again, installing Synaptic for that purpose only is ridiculous. And whatever happened to you is irrelevant. Those things tend *not* to happen to those who know how to install Nvidia cards and are up-to-date with all the relevant procedures. There are many ways to do something but only one is the "best practice". And sure, just removing the Nvidia drivers will give the same result as before, hence the need to use `nomodeset` until the proper Nvidia drivers are installed again.

Comment: We wouldn't be having this discussion if Ubuntu just simply included Synaptic like most proper Linux distros. Lacking that means lacking proper functionality of the PC in my opinion, because I should be able to search all the available packages in my repositories and not have to look it all up on AskUbuntu. Drivers also will have references to graphics card names in the descriptions of the packages in Synaptic... furthermore Synaptic makes finding `-dev` libraries for compiling much much easier due to the way the search function works.

Comment: by the way @celticwarrior `apt-get` is not necessary anymore. You can simply use `apt` now.  Also the `remove --purge` is no longer necessary as well. I changed my original answer to reflect all that.  `sudo apt purge nvidia-*` is perfectly suitable

Comment: Hi Emandudeguy. I wonder if you can help me again? After a big update, I'm still struggling with graphics drivers. I tried to follow your instructions regarding "sudo apt purge nvidia-*" and then using Synaptic package manager to "Mark nvidia-340 for installation". the installation fails, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey Kevin. it could be as simple as not restarting after you purge the nvidia driver. I believe you have to restart before reinstalling the nvidia driver. I could be wrong on that however it's worth a try.

Comment: If that doesn't work, though, after you've purged NVIDIA try doing "sudo apt update" before reinstalling the nvidia driver. Or if you want to do it in synaptic, click "edit" from the top menu, and then click "reload package information" (accomplishes the same task), and then mark nvidia-340 for installation and apply changes.

Comment: Hi, I've tried that and as soon as the replacement nvidia graphics driver is installed, I have exactly the same problem.. the login in / restart loop.

Comment: so, I've done " click "edit" from the top menu, and then click "reload package information"  and it's saying "could not download all repository indexes"

Comment: try doing what this thread here recommends https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/could-not-download-all-repository-indexes-what-does-that-mean-759976/ and report back. if that doesnt help, please try "sudo apt -f install" and then "sudo apt update" from the terminal and tell me what it says. If both those commands dont give errors, try installing the nvidia driver from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

After some effort I managed to get in to recovery mode by hitting "Del" at start up.

I was trying to find out where to open a terminal when I noticed an option to "repair damaged packages" so I gave that a shot.

Ubuntu repaired and reinstalled the graphics driver! Hey presto, it worked!!

Looks like I now have a fully functional computer.

Thanks very much for your help everyone.